# Sketchup to blender WITH textures?

Tags: three.js, blender, sketchup

I am working on a game in three.js and have some trouble adding some textures. When I put textures in Sketchup and then export the file as a collada file (.dae) and import it in blender, the textures is missing. Anyone know how tot fix this?

Comment: You should ask this on http://blender.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

First, you need go to edit mode and select all faces. Then in UV / Image editor, click Browse image (beside + icon) and select the texture of your model.

Done! Now, go back to Object mode and changes the 3d viewport to display textures.